# I want to stop order complete notification for local-pickup in wp-woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to stop order complete notification for local-pickup in  WP-woocommerce with this code in my child theme function.php but its not working Please anyone help me ...

```
function wc_stop_order_notification( $email_class ){

    global $post;

    $order = new WC_Order($post->ID);

    $wc_oreder_status = $post->post_status;

    $shiping_method_used_in = $order->get_shipping_method();


    if( $shiping_method_used_in == 'Local Pickup' && $wc_oreder_status == 'wc-completed'){

        remove_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed_notification', array( $email_class->emails['WC_Email_Customer_Completed_Order'], 'trigger' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_email', 'wc_stop_order_notification' ,99);
```

Answer (score 0):

'woocommerce_email' may not work. Use hook 'woocommerce_order_status_completed' instead.